# Execute command in remote active terminal

Tags: terminal, stdout, command, file-descriptors

Suppose you have a terminal emulator (T1) open with a PID of 6350.

From another terminal, type this command (C1):

```
echo "ls\n" > /proc/6350/fd/0
```

This writes `ls` and the new line in T1 but does not execute it. Why?

I also tried using `cat|bash` with `echo "ls\n" > /proc/catid/fd/0` but it is still not executed.

How can I echo the command into another terminal and have the command executed?

possible answer :

```
$ mkfifo toto;
$ bash < toto;
$ echo "ls" > toto;
```

In this case you cannot write anymore directly in the terminal (everything is displayed the same way the command (C1) displayed thing in this terminal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846033/help-sending-command-to-process-using-proc

Comment: I read that, but it is not very helpful.

Comment: It may not be "useful" as in giving you a way to do it, but it answers your question: you can't. You could tell us the end goal you're trying to accomplish and see if there's another way.

Comment: Ok you can't but then why the text is displayed in the other terminal ?

Comment: because you send the text to terminal interface, not to the shell.

Answer (score 15):

There is a command line utility called `ttyecho` that can send a command to another terminal (tty/pts) and have the command executed.

```
sudo ttyecho -n /dev/pts/5 ls
```

See: [Utility to Send Commands or Data to Other Terminals (tty/pts)](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/)

Also see: [`ttyecho` source code on github](https://github.com/aragua/ttyecho).

Another interesting tty command is `selector`, a real-time interactive pattern matcher in console that updates the tty input buffer.

```
# selector examples
selector -v -x @ <(find . -maxdepth 2 -type d | awk '{print $0"@cd "$0}')
selector -v -x @ <(grep -E -o 'http[^ ]+' fileWithURLS)
```

See: [selector - DYNAMIC SEARCH IN CONSOLE](http://www.idiap.ch/~fleuret/software.html#selector)

Comment: Sadly, the link to `ttyecho` source code on github seems to be broken. However, it seems to be available at https://github.com/osospeed/ttyecho instead, now.

Answer (score 9):

When you issue a write to `/dev/pts/X` (`/proc/6350/fd/0`, `1` and `2` is just a symlink to that), what happens is exactly the same thing that happens when process `6350` (or one of its children, suitably forked) outputs something: it writes to the terminal.

If you try to *read* from that device (`cat < /dev/pts/X`), funky things will happen. You should see the things you type in the original shell show up. (Quite possibly only after the first new line you typed - I'm guessing the terminal program (`xterm` or whatever you're using) does some line buffering, and the `6350` shell that was blocked on `read` gets that piece; then either shell might, or might not, win the subsequent reads, but I might very well be completely wrong on this.)

The thing is: when you read from or write to that device, you're not talking to the other shell that is using it. You're talking to the terminal emulator (`xterm` for example). Only the terminal emulator can inject data into that channel (what the shell reads), and all that the shell writes goes to the terminal. Attaching a second shell doesn't change that.

If you want to inject commands into that `6530` process, it will have to do that via the terminal (whether that's an X11 app or something else).

Recommended reading: [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)

Comment: Interestingly, reading from the pts (`cat /dev/pts/x`, you don't need `<`) I get the letters strictly alternating between the terminals.

Comment: Not using the redirection probably doesn't change much. I get non-predictable output either way.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. So `/proc/6350/fd/0` is a simlink to the stdin parent of `process 6350` which is a terminal. I guess it is the same for windowed applications ?