# is there any command like "wall" that runs a "command" in all terminals

Tags: fedora, shell-script, scripting, command

as you know "wall" command sends a message to all terminals:

```
wall message
```

now my question is this: is there any command that can send a "command" to be run in all terminals?
for example sending `clear` command to all terminals , so then all terminals will be cleared.

Comment: KDE's konsole can send input to all tabs (Edit->Copy Input to), but that of course can't work for virtual terminals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute command in remote active terminal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39145/execute-command-in-remote-active-terminal)

Comment: What do you want to do with this and why?

Answer (score 6):

That would be somewhat frightening, but you *can* send the output of any command to multiple "terminals". For instance, to clear all TTYs that you  have access to:

```
for tty in /dev/ttys00*; do clear > "$tty"; done # OS X (local)
for tty in /dev/pts/*; do clear > "$tty"; done # Linux (Ubuntu, via SSH)
```

Comment: For the purpose of the user's example (clearing all terminals), that's enough.

Comment: The subtlety of this is that one has to get the `TERM` environment variable right for each individual terminal, especially if one is doing more than clearing the screen.  But even clearing the screen varies by terminal type.  For real serial terminals, and for pseudo-terminals, this is quite the challenge, because there is no way to reliably tell what `TERM` should be set to, programmatically.  Then there are the terminal emulators that do not actually really clear their screens.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375784/5132

Answer (score 1):

Using George M command on Ubuntu gave me returned the following error

> ```
> bash: /dev/pts/ptmx: Permission denied
> ```

```
$ ls /dev/pts/
0  1  10  4  5  6  8  ptmx
```

So adding to it, I exclude ptmx in my alias in `~/.bash_aliases` by simply allowing 0-9.

```
alias clearall='for tty in /dev/pts/[0-9]; do clear > "$tty"; done'
```

Answer (score -2):

[Cluster SSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/).

`yum install cssh` after activating **rpmforge**.

Comment: This isn't even wrong, it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Gilles I'm not sure what's wrong with it; it seems fine

Comment: @MichaelMrozek What does coordinating multiple ssh sessions have to do with executing commands in multiple terminals?

Comment: @Gilles The description says "ClusterSSH controls a number of xterm windows via a single graphical console window"

Comment: @Gilles to issue actual commands you have to be owner of that terminal. I do not think that the question is about putting text onto a number of terminals. I suspect the questioner wants to do something on a number of machines with a single place to type the according commands. This is what Cluster-SSH is all about. Sadly the questioner has not answered the request for clarification.