# Why `clear` do not clear whole screen?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

When I use `clear` command to clear the screen. It is not cleared (see screenshot when I scroll up a bit after command done)

[image]

So I double the command to get right behavior:

```
$ clear && clear && DD=0 ...
```

[image]

Why do I need to double the command to get cleared screen?

**UPD**

Actually if I just `clear` I got cleared screen. But I can scroll up and see last 25lines (if screen is 80x25). When I run `clear;clear` I got those lines cleared.

Comment: Try `tput reset` instead of `clear`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The important thing to note here is the tag on the question.  This behaviour is specific to GNOME Terminal and any other terminal emulators that are built upon libvte.  You won't see this in Xterm, or in Unicode RXVT, or in the terminal emulator built into the Linux kernel, or on the FreeBSD console.

What happens in general is this.

1. The `clear` command looks at terminfo/termcap and issues appropriate control sequences.

   1. If the terminfo/termcap entry has an `E3` capability it, it first writes out that.  This issues control sequences to clear the scrollback buffer.  This and the history behind it are documented in detail in [the Dickey ncurses manual page for the `clear` command](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/clear.1.html).
   2. It then uses the `clear` capability to clear the visible screen.
2. The control sequences in the terminfo/termcap entry are determined by the terminal type; but, with the exceptions of the (nowadays rare) terminals that use FormFeed to clear the screen (which DEC VTs and their imitators do not), they are either just plain old ECMA-48 control sequences or extensions thereto.  For examples:

   - [The `putty` entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty) defines `E3=\E[3J` which is the Xterm extension control sequence.
   - [The NetBSD console's `pcvtxx` entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-pcvt_X_X) is one of many that define `clear=\E[H\E[J` or something similar.  This is two ordinary ECMA-48 control sequences.
3. The terminal emulator acts upon the control sequences.  As defined by ECMA-48 and the Xterm extension to it:

   - CSI `H` (CUP) homes the cursor.
   - CSI `0` `J` (ED 0) or just CSI `J` erases from the current cursor position to the end of the screen.
   - CSI `2` `J` (ED 2) erases the whole screen.
   - CSI `3` `J` (ED 3) erases the scrollback buffer.

When it comes to GNOME Terminal in particular:

1. The terminal type is properly `gnome`, but some people leave it erroneously set to `xterm`.
2. [The `gnome` terminfo entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-gnome) does not define an `E3` capability, and on many systems — still! — neither does the `xterm` entry as this has not percolated down from [Dickey terminfo](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-xterm-basic).  So `clear` just writes out the contents of the `clear` capability.
3. The contents of the `clear` capability for those terminfo entries are the control sequences to home the cursor followed by erase the whole screen.
4. **But GNOME Terminal does not implement erase the whole screen correctly.**  More specifically, the library that it is based upon, libvte, does not do that in the code of [its `VteTerminalPrivate::seq_clear_screen()` function](https://github.com/GNOME/vte/blob/af889244f9306d8686c6346da35f34694240882e/src/vteseq.cc#L239).  Rather, libvte scrolls the screen down an entire screen's worth of blank lines, and moves the cursor position to the first of those blank lines.

This is why you see what you see.  libvte is not erasing the whole screen when told to.  Rather it is doing something that has a superficial resemblance to that, until one does exactly what the questioner has done here: scroll the terminal window back to look at the scroll back buffer.  Then the difference is blatant.

On other terminal emulators such as Xterm and Unicode RXVT, the ED 2 control sequence really does erase the screen, erasing every position on the screen in place, from the top down, and not altering the scrollback buffer.  But on libvte terminal emulators, it just pushes the current screen up into the scrollback buffer and adds a screen's worth of blank lines.  The prior screen contents are not erased but shifted into the scrollback buffer.

And if you run the `clear` command twice, it adds *two* screen's worth of blank lines.  If your scroll back buffer is large enough, you can *still* find the original screen contents, simply further up in the scrollback buffer.

## Further reading

- *Control Functions for Coded Character Sets*.  ECMA-48.  1976.
- Georgi Kirilov (2007-12-30). *[Ctrl-L adds blank space to the scrollback buffer](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=506438)*.  GNOME bug #506438.
- [To what extent are the xterm, xterm-color, and linux terminal emulators based on VT100?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324306/)
- [Clearing the "old" scrollback buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87469/)
- [Bash clear command weird behavior deletes scrollback buffer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318262/)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1094599/
- Thomas Dickey (2018). "[Known Bugs in XTerm and Look–alikes: GNOME Terminal](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#bug_gnometerm)".  *XTerm Frequently Asked Questions*.  invisible-island.net.
- Thomas Dickey (2018). "[Known Bugs in XTerm and Look–alikes: Notes on VTE](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#vte_widget)".  *XTerm Frequently Asked Questions*.  invisible-island.net.

Comment: Maybe to do `alias clear='clear && printf "\033[3J"'` is a viable solution ?

Comment: "The terminal type is properly `gnome`, but some people leave it erroneously set to `xterm`." – This is not true. gnome-terminal (VTE) has for many years defaulted to "xterm" and later "xterm-256color". This is the choice made by its developers, and used by them for testing/developing. Its emulation is reasonably close to xterm's in practice, and the `gnome` terminal description is abandoned. Sure piggybacking another terminal description has plenty of downsides, but so is maintaining a separate one, it's two far-less-than-ideal possibilities the project had to choose between.

Comment: "But GNOME Terminal does not implement erase the whole screen correctly." – This is indeed one of the places where VTE differs from xterm, you even linked its tracking bug. Note that xterm's behavior has drawbacks too that VTE doesn't, e.g. pressing Ctrl+L in bash wipes out the last screenful of data in xterm, but not in gnome-terminal.

Comment: The `gnome-*` and `vte-*` family of terminfo entries is most definitely _not_ abandoned, and indeed was most recently updated as I write this in July 2017 and January 2018.  And it most definitely _is_ true that it is erroneous to use `xterm` for it.  The GNOME developers are quite wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the terminal and destroy the whole output buffer, I'd recommend doing `tput reset`. That will definitely clear the terminal and fix its state as a bonus if e.g. any previous program crashed and left the terminal in unclean state. In addition, the `tput` should be clever enough to figure the correct terminal type so you don't need to know if your terminal uses VT100 or some other command sequences.

As `tput reset` is defined by POSIX, it should work in any POSIX compatible system, too: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/tput.html

Comment: It is specifically specified by POSIX to reset the terminal "in an implementation-defined manner".  For example, on my system, it does absolutely nothing (in particular, it does not clear the screen nor the scrollback buffer).

Comment: @Kusalananda Wow! I didn't expect any terminal to reset without clearing the screen. Which terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: Konsole is the only terminal I use that doesn't clear the scrollback with `tput reset`. It seems that Konsole version 21.12.3 requires `<ESC>c` to clear the screen and `<ESC>[3J` to delete the scrollback buffer but that doesn't clear the screen. As a result, `echo -ne '\e[3J\ec'` should be able to clear the scrollback and the screen but this is not portable.

Comment: iTerm on macOS, with an SSH session running `tmux` inside on an OpenBSD system. That `tput reset` command does clear the terminal in iTerm locally, but does not reset the scrollback buffer.