# Zsh clear scrollback buffer

Tags: shell, zsh, interactive

With Bash <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> will clear the screen but not scrollback
buffer. In the past I have worked around this by using:

```
tput reset
```

However I have noticed that this command will not clear the scrollback buffer
with Zsh. So, how is it done?

Comment: It's remotely possible that there's a bash alias for `tput` (though the bash style tends to be hard-coded escape sequences).  Perhaps the `TERM` (and corresponding *reset* differ: some use the hard-reset, some don't).

Comment: Works for me, but this depends on the terminal. Which terminal emulator are you using? Do you have the same problem in other terminal emulators? Are you using an interface such as screen or tmux? Do you, at any point (e.g. in your zsh configuration, or in your `.profile`, or in your terminal configuration, or anywhere else), change the value of the `TERM` environment variable?

Comment: @Gilles I am just using stock Manjaro from here https://osdn.net/projects/manjaro/storage/xfce

Answer (score 11):

```bsh
function clear-scrollback-buffer {
  # Behavior of clear: 
  # 1. clear scrollback if E3 cap is supported (terminal, platform specific)
  # 2. then clear visible screen
  # For some terminal 'e[3J' need to be sent explicitly to clear scrollback
  clear && printf '\e[3J'
  # .reset-prompt: bypass the zsh-syntax-highlighting wrapper
  # https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/1026
  # https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/107#issuecomment-183824034
  # -R: redisplay the prompt to avoid old prompts being eaten up
  # https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k/pull/1176#discussion_r299303453
  zle && zle .reset-prompt && zle -R
}

zle -N clear-scrollback-buffer
bindkey '^L' clear-scrollback-buffer
```

`clear` and `zle .reset-prompt && zle -R` are added to make sure it works for multiline prompts, which is important.

References

- [What does `clear` do](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375784/246718)
- [Clearing the buffer without clearing the status line](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt/issues/676#issuecomment-496939823)

Comment: That's for iterm2, while OP is asking about VTE (the two do not behave the same).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Yes, you're right. The sequence code is for xterm, not VTE. I missed it.

Comment: You can achieve the same in one step `printf "\ec\e[3J"`

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>
- *Menus* / *Edit* / *Clear to Start*

Comment: What terminal is this for?