# Running Custom commands in a Terminal Application

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, gnome-terminal

I'm running a terminal application in `/dev/pts/X` terminal that has its own console as:

[image]

What I need is to run commands specific to this application but from another terminal.

Using `ttyecho` does not work as it interacts with the shell not with the application running  on the shell.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? What commands? Do you want to use one terminal emulator to launch commands in another?

Comment: i need to run commands specific to this console but from another terminal/python script

Comment: Ah, OK, you can do this using [`ttyecho`](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/#.U7p1QaZclMk) as described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39145/22222). I will close this as a duplicate. If the linked answer does not solve it for you, please [edit] to explain how it failed and the post will be reopened.

Comment: Did you try it? I tried with an interactive python shell open in the other terminal and it executed the python commands I passed it.

Comment: hmm sorry! thanks for your inputs mistake was on my side now i am able to run  it perfectly thanks again

Comment: @psycic - does `ttyecho` not work for you? The edit to your Q is confusing at the end.